# Why is the record UI truncating a formula field?

Tags: reporting, formula-field, ui

I have a formula field (text) that seems to work as expected. I say this because I pull a report, and the column with the field shows ABC123 XYZ 4567 (not exactly, but that's the gist). Anyway, I'm confident in our actual data because the report would be pulling, I'm assuming, the most direct data and it's correct.

However, a user called to my attention that for these records, when viewed in the UI (ie. going to the record view in the UI rather than just looking at the report values) the displayed value is simply, for example, ABC123 (consistently with the second portion missing). It's confusing because

1. Even though it's a text field, when you create a formula, there isn't an option for a limit on characters (at least, none that I have seen) and
2. The report shows the complete value!

Is this a bug, or is there something I should look into?

Comment: Just want to be sure, are you comparing the same field? It's possible the field on the report isn't the same field on the record page layout (same label but not the same API name).

Comment: I didn't check this, I definitely should have! Good thinking, but no, there is only one...

Comment: Are you viewing the record through a standard page layout, or a custom VF page or Lightning Component? In Lightning Experience or Classic?

Comment: standard, just field on a layout, no bells or whistles, VF pages...components...really nothing, just field on the layout. Classic, not lightning

Comment: What's even more odd is...the more I look at this field formula and the specific records, it actually seems like the value in the UI is correct and the report values are wrong. This is so much stranger to me, since I'd expect the report to pull the most direct value. Might have to benchmark this, but I still don't know why the two would be different. Very, very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ultimately just a bug, which is pretty lame. No reason to keep this open and, unfortunately, nothing valuable to take away from it. Thanks to all who contributed with troubleshooting